# Why dictionaries (dict_items) support union (__or__) but not addition (__add__)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example to illustrate:

```
>>> a = dict(eggs='eggs', spam='spam')
>>> b = dict(spam='spam', ham='ham')
>>> dict(a.items() | b.items())
{'eggs': 'eggs', 'ham': 'ham', 'spam': 'spam'}
```

Meanwhile...

```
>>> dict(a.items() + b.items())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'
```

Is there a reason for this? Wouldn't it be reasonable to assume that addition and union should do the same for dictionaries?

In Python 2 this works perfectly fine:

```
>>> dict(a.items() + b.items())
{'eggs': 'eggs', 'ham': 'ham', 'spam': 'spam'}
```

Although in Python 2 `.items()` returns a regular list (in contrast to `dict_items`), so maybe it's by accident.

---

Finally, I don't think "what happens if keys have different values"-dilemma applies here as operator `|` doesn't seem to mind anyway (one of two values is selected seemingly at random).

Comment: Btw, I'm only asking why it's not supported (or is there any reason at all). I dont have a concrete use-case I'm trying to solve - I'm just curious.

Answer (score 3):

Some `dict` views ([notably not `dict.values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)) support [set operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).  `+` isn't a set operation, so there's no real reason it should be included.

Comment: Yes, it's not, however! `-` is supported. That's why it seemed inconsistent to me.

Comment: [Because `set`s support `-` as difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference).  They do so because that's the existing mathematical notation.

Comment: what would you expect `+` to do with a set? It's actually pretty problematic if you think about it, which is why `|`, `^` and `&` exist for combining sets in ways that are clear.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit to @Patrick's answer, the `dict_items` object is a subclass of `collections.Set`

```
from collections.abc import Set

isinstance(d.items(), Set) # True
```

and `Set` doesn't have the `+` operation:

```
'__add__' in dir(Set) # False
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's fall back to the most basic Python mantra: the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

So you're asking why `+` shouldn't be defined to do the same thing as `|`. Your answer is right there: there would be two equally correct ways to do the same thing, which would not be Pythonic.